# Unable to execute my GUI "Group layout can only by use with one cointainer at a time"

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to execute my auto- generated GUI to make it visible, However this error message appear every time I tried to execute it from my "main" in another class.

This is the way I using

```
public class Results {

   // main method
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
       ResultQueries rq = new ResultQueries();
       ResultView rv = new ResultView(); 
       ResultPresenter rp = new ResultPresenter( rv, rq );
       rv.bind(rp);

       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ResultView().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

And this is my GUI

```
package Results;

import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Carlos
 */
public class ResultView extends javax.swing.JFrame implements IResultView{

    /**
     * Creates new form ResultView
     */
    private ResultPresenter presenter;
    private List< Result > results;  
    private ResultQueries resultQueries;

    @SuppressWarnings("OverridableMethodCallInConstructor")
    public ResultView() {

          super( "Result" ); 

      // establish database connection and set up PreparedStatements
      resultQueries = new ResultQueries(); 
       jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        jLabel1.setText("Input");

        jLabel2.setText("Output");

        jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");

        jLabel4.setText("jLabel4");

        jLabel5.setText("jLabel5");

        jLabel6.setText("jLabel6");

        jLabel7.setText("jLabel7");

        jLabel8.setText("jLabel8");

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

        jTextField3.setText("jTextField3");

        jTextField4.setText("jTextField4");

        jTextField5.setText("jTextField5");

        jTextField6.setText("jTextField6");

        jLabel9.setText("jLabel9");

        jTextField7.setText("jTextField7");

        jTextField8.setText("jTextField8");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");

        jLabel10.setText("Queries");

        jButton3.setText("jButton3");

        jButton4.setText("jButton4");

        jButton5.setText("jButton5");

        jButton6.setText("jButton6");

        jButton7.setText("jButton7");

        jButton8.setText("jButton8");

        jButton9.setText("jButton9");

        jButton10.setText("jButton10");
        jButton10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton10ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton11.setText("jButton11");
        jButton11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton11ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jButton3)
                                            .addComponent(jButton2))
                                        .addGap(175, 175, 175)
                                        .addComponent(jButton10)
                                        .addGap(134, 134, 134)
                                        .addComponent(jButton11))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addComponent(jButton4))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton8))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jButton7)
                                    .addComponent(jButton6)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addGap(123, 123, 123)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 937, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton9))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton5))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19)))
                .addGap(80, 80, 80))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4))
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                            .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 393, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                                .addGap(3, 3, 3))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton5)
                                .addGap(17, 17, 17)))
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton6)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton7)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton8)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton10)
                        .addComponent(jButton11))
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton9)
                .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))

        );



    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String rs = "";

        results = resultQueries.getResultsForAllStudents();


for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            rs+=results.get(i).toString()+"\n";
        }

        jTextArea1.setText(rs);

    }                                        

    private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
      presenter.showPrevious();
    }                                         

    private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        presenter.showNext();
    }                                         


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
    // End of variables declaration                   

/*this button  takes the Textfield information to execute the query get student by ID*/
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        if (jTextField1.getText().equals("") )
                {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Introduce student ID", "Not information found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
        else
        {
      String rs="";        
      results = resultQueries.getResultForStudent(jTextField1.getText());

      for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            rs+=results.get(i).toString()+"\n";
        }

        jTextArea1.setText(rs);

        }


    }                                        
/*this button takes information from two text field to establish Minimum and Maximun in order to execute getTotalMark in range method and display results*/
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        if (jTextField7.getText().equals("") || jTextField8.getText().equals(""))
                {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Introduce a range of numbers", "Not information found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
        else
        {
        String rs=""; 

        int a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText()) ;
        int b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText());
        results = resultQueries.getTotalMarksInRange(a, b);

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            rs+=results.get(i).toString()+"\n";
        }

        jTextArea1.setText(rs);



        }

    }                                        
/*This button execute the query getAbsentFils and show the results stired in the list*/
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         



       int results = resultQueries.getNumberofAbsentFails(  );
        jTextArea1.setText("The Number of Absent Fail is: " +Integer.toString(results));


    }                                        

    /*This button takes the input from exam text field and update the exam mark with the query*/
    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

     if (jTextField1.getText().equals("")|| jTextField4.getText().equals("")){


             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Introduce student ID and Exam mark", "Not information found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
          }
     else{
        int a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()) ;
        String b = jTextField1.getText();
       resultQueries.updateExamMark(a,b);
       jTextArea1.setText("Information Updated");

     }
    }   

    // End of variables declaration   

    public void bind( ResultPresenter rp) {
       presenter = rp;
   }

    public void setjTextField1(String s) { jTextField1.setText(s); } 
    public String getjTextField1() { return jTextField1.getText(); }

    public void setjTextField2(int i) { jTextField2.setText(Integer.toString(i)); }
    public String getjTextField2() { return jTextField2.getText(); }

    public void setjTextField3(int i) { jTextField3.setText(Integer.toString(i)); } 
    public String getjTextField3() { return jTextField3.getText(); }

    public void setjTextField4(String s) { jTextField4.setText(s); }
    public String getjTextField4() { return jTextField4.getText(); }

    public void setjTextField5(String s) { jTextField5.setText(s); } 
    public String getjTextField5() { return jTextField5.getText(); } 

    public void setjTextField6(String s) { jTextField6.setText(s); }
    public String getjTextField6() { return jTextField6.getText(); }

    public void setjTextField7(String s) { jTextField7.setText(s); }
    public String getjTextField7() { return jTextField7.getText(); }

    public void setjTextField8(String s) { jTextField8.setText(s); }
    public String getjTextField8() { return jTextField8.getText(); }

    //public void enableNext() { nextButton.setEnabled( true ); }
    //public void enablePrevious() { previousButton.setEnabled( true ); }

    public void showMessageDialog(String s1, String s2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, s1, s2, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used.

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this.getContentPane());
            this.setLayout(layout);
```